# ASP GridView to be updated automatically when ModalDialog is closed

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sharepoint-2010

I have a gridView with search and filtering options, it is listing document from SharePoint Library, when i click on the Document name i added a Modal popup to display Documents properties page, if i update Document's title for example and select save, the item is updated but the gridview is still showing the old title, i need to press Search again in order to refresh the values.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

the code i use for model popup is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function openModal(url) {
        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
        options.url = url;
        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }

    // Dialog callback 
    function CloseCallback(result, target) {
        if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {

            SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
        }
    }
  </script>
```

what should i do to refresh and bid gridview data when the popup is closed?

Answer (score 0):

on the click of `save` button, make a serverside call to rebind the gridview. i.e

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('id_of_save_button').click(function(){
          //ajax call of serverside method to rebind the grid.
    });
});
```

However with asp.net these things become little easy if you use `modalPopupExtender` that ships with asp.net

Comment: Bu the Save button is automatically shown in SharePoint EditForm.aspx, it is not a custom button.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for handling sharepoint save event using javascript u can use this function

```
function PreSaveAction() 
 {
   // write your gride view data bind code
 }
```

Comment: just add this any where in your page script

Comment: Hi;
 i have put  function PreSaveAction() {
        window.alert("test");
    } 
in usercontrol.ascx page but it was not fired! any idea??